# Find the mean of determinant of matrix with random elements

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Suppose we have $A - n \times n$ matrix with independent and equaly ditributed values. $Pr(A[i][j] = 1) = p, Pr(A[i][j] = 0) = 1-p$.

Find $E(det(A - A^T))$.

I know that $A - A^T$ is a skew-symmetric matrix and so for odd n we have that $det(A - A^T) = 0$. But what can we say about $det(A - A^T)$, when n is even? In one post on stack exchange I saw that this determinant isn't negative, but how can I calculate it? Anyway thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of an antisymmetric matrix of even order is the square of a polynomial with respect to the entries of this matrix, called Pfaffian. For instance if the matrix has order 4 the pfaffian has the form $P=x_1x_2-x_3x_4+x_5x_6$ -check with wikipedia. Since $X_1,\ldots,X_6$ are iid with distribution $\Pr(X_i=\pm 1)=pq$ and $\Pr(X_i=0)=1-2pq$ then $\Pr(X_1X_2=\pm 1) =2p^2q^2$ and $\Pr(X_1X_2=0)=1-4p^2q^2$ Denoting $Y_1=X_1X_2, \ Y_2=-X_3X_4,\ Y_3=X_5X_6$ which are iid with zero expectation and $P=Y_1+Y_2+Y_3.$ Therefore the determinant $D=P^2$ has expectation
$$E(D)=\sum_i E(Y_i^2)+2\sum_{i<j}E(Y_iY_j)=12p^2q^2$$

It is probably possible to generalize from 4 to 2n using the general formula of Pfaffian given for instance in Wikipedia. Too much work for me today.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n = 2d$ and $B = A - A^{\mathrm t}$.  Then all entries of $B$ are pair-wise independent except for pairs $\{B_{ij}, B_{ji}\}$. Moreover, $\mathbb E(B_{ij})=0$ for all entries, and $\mathbb E(B_{ij}B_{ji}) = -2 p q$ for $i \neq j$.  Now $$\mathbb E(\det(B)) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \mathbb E(\prod_{i=1}^n B_{i \sigma(i)})$$ and the expectation of each product is non-zero only when $\sigma$ is a product of $d$ disjoint $2$-cycles. (Each $B_{ij}$ that appears *must* be paired with $B_{ji}$.) In that case $$\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \mathbb E(\prod_{i=1}^n B_{i \sigma(i)}) = (2 p q)^d.$$ Since there are $(n-1)!! = 1\cdot 3 \cdot \cdots \cdot (n-1)$ such permutations in $S_n$ we get $$\mathbb E(\det(B)) = (n-1)!! (2pq)^d.$$ For $d=2$ this indeed gives the result in Gérard’s answer.